Overall column not in the right place in a gt_summary table
I hope you are doing all well ?
I have this issue when I generate a tbl_summary table, an issue I didn't  have when I was working with the older version of the package, but since I downloaded the latest version it just doesn't work correctly,(see attached pictures, the correct table is under the older version of the package and the messed one is under the latest version) is there any solution to this ?
Old version of gtsummary:

New version of gtsummary:

here's my code (Updated to make it simple to reproduce, I took off the flextable code and the labels but everything is in the same order)
groupe_etude <- c(rep("Tem",13),rep("TTA-",7),rep("TTA+",18))
tympan_g_inc <- rep(1,38)
tympan_d_inc <- rep(1,38)
cou_inc <- c(rep(1,3),rep(0,34),1)
pavillon_inc <- c(rep(1,3),rep(0,34),1)
luette_inc <- c(rep(1,37),2)
dysmorph_inc <- rep(0,38)


example_df <- data.frame(groupe_etude,tympan_g_inc,tympan_d_inc,cou_inc,pavillon_inc,luette_inc,dysmorph_inc,row.names=NULL)

example_df %>% 
  mutate(luette_inc = as.factor(luette_inc)) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = groupe_etude,
              include = c(tympan_g_inc:dysmorph_inc),
              digits = everything()~c(0,0),
              value = list(c(tympan_g_inc,tympan_d_inc) ~ "1",
                           dysmorph_inc~"0"),
              percent = "column") %>%
  add_overall(last=FALSE)

The variables (tympan_g_inc, tympan_d_inc and dysmorph_inc) are coded as integers dichotomus (0, 1)
For this one I have found the solution in an old question here (tbl_summary(): Trouble reporting 0% results for dichotomous variables)
value = list(c(tympan_g_inc,tympan_d_inc) ~ "1",
                                               dysmorph_inc~"0")

It works perfectly.
But, I don't understand why the overall column is showing in that place I tried the argument last=FALSE it doesn't change anything.
Thanks in advance

Please update your post with code we can run on our machines, aka a minimal reproducible example. Review reprex.tidyverse.org for details.

Hello Daniel, I updated my post.

Thanks for updating. Can you please remove all extraneous code? Please make the example as minimal as possible while illustrating your issue.

Hello Daniel, I took off the flextable code and labels but everything is in the same order. Thanks in advance.

I spent a lot of time looking at this and it was an "Ah ha!" moment that led me to the answer. This is an encoding issue. I ran into the same problem, for an entirely different reason.
If you were to run sort(groupe_etude), you would see the order is Tem, TTA-, and TT+. However, if you run data.frame(x = groupe_etude) %>% arrange(x), the order is TTA+, TTA-, and Tem. In one area of gtsummary's code, it orders it as you indicated with by, in another area, it's ordered with dplyr::arrange, thus creating an odd order when overall is added.
Thankfully, the fix isn't too much more than what you've already done.
example_df %>% 
  mutate(luette_inc = as.factor(luette_inc),
         groupe_etude = factor(groupe_etude)) %>%   #  <<----- I'm new!
  tbl_summary(by = groupe_etude,
              include = c(tympan_g_inc:dysmorph_inc),
              digits = everything()~c(0,0),
              value = list(c(tympan_g_inc,tympan_d_inc) ~ "1",
                           dysmorph_inc~"0"),
              percent = "column") %>%
  add_overall(last=FALSE)



It works perfectly. Thank you so much Kat.

Thanks for the reproducible example. You've found a bug that is a result of sort() and dplyr::arrange() sorting differently in some edge cases. If you'd like, you can track the progress of this fix in this github issue: https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/2038
In the meantime, here's how you can manually move the column.
library(gtsummary)

example_df <- 
  data.frame(
    groupe_etude = c(rep("Tem", 13), rep("TTA-", 7), rep("TTA+", 18)),
    tympan_g_inc = rep(1,38)
  )

example_df |> 
  tbl_summary(by = groupe_etude, include = tympan_g_inc) |> 
  add_overall() |> 
  modify_table_body(~.x |> dplyr::relocate(stat_0, .after = label)) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO




Characteristic
Overall N = 38
Tem N = 13
TTA- N = 7
TTA+ N = 18




tympan_g_inc






1
38 (100%)
13 (100%)
7 (100%)
18 (100%)



Created on 2024-10-11 with reprex v2.1.1

Ahh, the page updated after I posted and saw that @Kat already posted a wonderful solution :)

Yeah I thought about this solution too but since I have generated tons of tables, I was looking for a fast automatic solution :p Thank you so much Daniel.

You can always so install the package from GitHub since the issue has already been addressed
